# change annotation image after its created

Tags: ios, ios5, mkmapview

I have a custom annotation that sets its image based on the type of the annotation using the viewForAnnotation delegate method. Im only using 1 annotation that represents a car moving and want to change the image for when the car is detected to be moving and stopped. How could I go about this besides removing my annotation and re-adding it which causes a blink?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Wherever you detect that the car's state has changed, retrieve the annotation's current view using the `MKMapView` *instance* method `viewForAnnotation:`.  This is not the same as the `mapView:viewForAnnotation:` *delegate* method.

After getting the current view for the annotation, you can modify its properties including `image`.

Also make sure the `mapView:viewForAnnotation:` delegate method has the same exact condition to set `image` based on the state of the car annotation.  You may want to put the logic in a common method called from both places (where the state changes and the delegate method) so the code isn't duplicated.

For example, where the state changes, you might have:

```
//carAnnotation is your id<MKAnnotation> object
MKAnnotationView *av = [mapView viewForAnnotation:carAnnotation];
if (carAnnotation.isMoving)
    av.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"moving.png"];
else
    av.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"stopped.png"];
```

The `if` statement (or whatever logic you have to set `image`) is the part that should also be in the `viewForAnnotation` delegate method.