# Update annotation image dynamically

Tags: swift, annotations, mkmapview, mkannotation

I'm trying to update a custom annotation image dynamically but couldn't get it done. I have a custom annotation class that is of type `MKPointAnnotation` which returns image name. Below is the code I have been working with...

```
class CustomAnnotation: MKPointAnnotation {
    var imageName: String!
}
```

And based on the data I get from the server I'm changing the image name of the annotation:

```
self.annotation.imageName = "xyz.png";
```

I could see the updated image after I exit the view controller and reopening it again. Is there a way to update it dynamically without switching back and forth?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6808792/change-uiimage-from-mkannotation-in-the-mkmapview and 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10439335/change-annotation-image-after-its-created for one approach (will need to convert to Swift).  Another approach is to create a custom annotation _view_ class that observes changes to its associated annotation's imageName and updates its (the view's) image property.

Comment: @Anna I did exactly the way you suggested but in Swift. It's throwing error at this line of code `var test: MKAnnotationView = self.mapView.viewForAnnotation(self.annotation);` -> `found nil while unwrapping it.` I didn't understand your second suggestion. Could you give some more insight on that pls?